# Typo3 RTE userElements

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte, tsconfig

I'm trying to add a userElement to my RTE, but if I click on the icon for userelements (I hope it is the right icon, I never used that before) an empty window opens...

[image: rte]

Is there something wrong on my Page TSConfig:

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTags := addToList(star)
RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(star)
RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags

RTE.default.showButtons = *
RTE.default.hideButtons ()

RTE.default.userElements.10 = Own Tags
// tag configuration
RTE.default.userElements.10.1 = Stars
RTE.default.userElements.10.1.description = The selected text will be wrapped with <star></star>
RTE.default.userElements.10.1.mode = wrap
RTE.default.userElements.10.1.content = <star>|</star>
```

And the Typoscript:

```
lib.parseFunc.allowTags := addToList(star)
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(star)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem with this Configuration in Page TSConfig:
<kbd>Edit page</kbd> > <kbd>Resources tab</kbd>

```
RTE.default {
  disableEnterParagraphs = 1
  userElements.10 = PDF Optionen
  userElements.10 {
    6 = Pagebreak
    6.description = Manueller Seitenumbruch im PDF
    6.mode = wrap
    6.content = <div class="pagebreak">|</div>    
  }
}
RTE.default {
   showButtons := addToList(user)
   removeTags := removeFromList(user)
   proc.HTMLparser_rte.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
   proc.HTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
   proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
}
```